# Logical Error in Program

Tags: c++

I tried using cout at various stages to figure but in vain. The program crashes after flushing the first two values in the reversed list. It prints a garbage value as the third value and before it can print the last two values, it crashes.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class LLStack {
    public:
        struct Node {
            int data;
            Node* next;
            Node(int n) {
                data = n;
                next = 0;
            }
            Node(int n, Node* node) {
                data = n;
                next = node;
            }
        };
        LLStack();
        LLStack(const LLStack&);
        LLStack& operator = (const LLStack&);
        ~LLStack();
        void push(int);
        int pop();
        int top();
        bool isEmpty();
        void flush();

    private:
        Node* head;

};

LLStack::LLStack() {
    head = 0;
}

LLStack::LLStack(const LLStack& s) {
    head = new Node(NULL);
    head->data = s.head->data;
    if (s.head->next != NULL) {
        head->next = new Node(*(s.head->next));
    }
    else {
        head->next = new Node(NULL);
    }

}

LLStack::~LLStack() {
    this->flush();
}

LLStack& LLStack::operator = (const LLStack& s) {
    this->head = new Node(NULL);
    this->head->data = s.head->data;
    if (s.head->next != NULL) {
        this->head->next = new Node(*(s.head->next));
    }
    else {
        this->head->next = new Node(NULL);
    }

    return *this;
}

void LLStack::push(int x) {
    if (head == 0) head = new Node(x);
    else {
        Node* temp = new Node(x, head);
        head = temp;
    }
}

int LLStack::pop() {
    if (head == 0) {
        cout << "\n\nNo elements to pop\n\n";
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        Node* temp = head;
        int n = temp->data;
        head = temp->next;
        delete temp;
        return n;
    }
}

int LLStack::top() {
    if (head == 0) {
        cout << "\n\nNo elements in the stack\n\n";
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return head->data;
    }
}

bool LLStack::isEmpty() {
    return (head == 0);
}

void LLStack::flush() {

    if (head == 0) {
        cout << "\n\nNo elements in the Stack to flush\n\n";
        return;
    }
    cout << "\n\nFlushing the Stack:  ";
    Node* temp = 0;
    while (head != 0) {
        temp = head;
        cout << temp->data << "  ";
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}

void reverseStack(LLStack& s1) {
    LLStack s2;
    while (!s1.isEmpty()) {
        s2.push(s1.pop());
    }
    s1 = s2;
}

int main() {

    LLStack s;
    s.push(1);
    s.push(2);
    s.push(3);
    s.push(4);
    s.push(5);
    reverseStack(s);
    cout << "\n\nFlushing s:\n";
    s.flush();
    return 0;
}
```

I tried using cout at various stages to figure but in vain. The program crashes after flushing the first two values in the reversed list. It prints a garbage value as the third value and before it can print the last two values, it crashes.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class LLStack {
    public:
        struct Node {
            int data;
            Node* next;
            Node(int n) {
                data = n;
                next = 0;
            }
            Node(int n, Node* node) {
                data = n;
                next = node;
            }
        };
        LLStack();
        LLStack(const LLStack&);
        LLStack& operator = (const LLStack&);
        ~LLStack();
        void push(int);
        int pop();
        int top();
        bool isEmpty();
        void flush();

    private:
        Node* head;

};

LLStack::LLStack() {
    head = 0;
}

LLStack::LLStack(const LLStack& s) {
    head = new Node(NULL);
    head->data = s.head->data;
    if (s.head->next != NULL) {
        head->next = new Node(*(s.head->next));
    }
    else {
        head->next = new Node(NULL);
    }

}

LLStack::~LLStack() {
    this->flush();
}

LLStack& LLStack::operator = (const LLStack& s) {
    this->head = new Node(NULL);
    this->head->data = s.head->data;
    if (s.head->next != NULL) {
        this->head->next = new Node(*(s.head->next));
    }
    else {
        this->head->next = new Node(NULL);
    }

    return *this;
}

void LLStack::push(int x) {
    if (head == 0) head = new Node(x);
    else {
        Node* temp = new Node(x, head);
        head = temp;
    }
}

int LLStack::pop() {
    if (head == 0) {
        cout << "\n\nNo elements to pop\n\n";
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        Node* temp = head;
        int n = temp->data;
        head = temp->next;
        delete temp;
        return n;
    }
}

int LLStack::top() {
    if (head == 0) {
        cout << "\n\nNo elements in the stack\n\n";
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return head->data;
    }
}

bool LLStack::isEmpty() {
    return (head == 0);
}

void LLStack::flush() {

    if (head == 0) {
        cout << "\n\nNo elements in the Stack to flush\n\n";
        return;
    }
    cout << "\n\nFlushing the Stack:  ";
    Node* temp = 0;
    while (head != 0) {
        temp = head;
        cout << temp->data << "  ";
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}

void reverseStack(LLStack& s1) {
    LLStack s2;
    while (!s1.isEmpty()) {
        s2.push(s1.pop());
    }
    s1 = s2;
}

int main() {

    LLStack s;
    s.push(1);
    s.push(2);
    s.push(3);
    s.push(4);
    s.push(5);
    reverseStack(s);
    cout << "\n\nFlushing s:\n";
    s.flush();
    return 0;
}
```

Please run it and you'll understand for yourself.

Comment: Using a debugger would probably help you a lot more than outputs.

Comment: Actually, I figured out. The problem is that flush is getting called twice. Once in the destructor and then explicitly by us. I want us to be able to call flush whenever we want. So, how do I fix the destructor. Just removing flush in the destructor is not a good option.

Comment: IDK how to use a debugger. I don't have time ATM as I got an exam in 6 hours.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in function:

```
void reverseStack(LLStack& s1) {
    LLStack s2;
    while (!s1.isEmpty()) {
        s2.push(s1.pop());
    }
    s1 = s2;
}
```

Here you are creating the local stack "s2". When the s2 goes out of scope, it calls the destructor and flushes the whole stack. Better you should remove the flush call from destructor or create the global "s2". Best option will be implement the other logic to reverse the stack.

Comment: Even if s2 goes out of scope, it's data will be coped into s1 because I'm defining my own copy constructor.

Comment: I didn't see that. Here is the catch in assignment operator you should have used the loop to create the new nodes and copy the nodes from other stack. You have used only if condition which is creating only single node.

Comment: @GuptillGunther No, it's not copied, unless you have also defined an assignment operator.